# How to Train a Hugging Face GPT2Tokenizer using your own words?

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

The Hugging Face `transformers` library provide a tokenizer `GPT2Tokenizer` which is already pretrained. However, I want to train a tokenizer from scratch while using the same config as `GPT2Tokenizer` other than the `vocab_size`. This will be used to train a GPT model of another language from scratch.

Is it possible to retrain a `GPT2Tokenizer` using your own list of sentences/words?

Tried running the following code

```py
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2')
tokenizer.pre_tokenizer = Whitespace()
tokenizer.train_from_iterator(my_list_of_words, vocab_size=10000, min_frequency=1, 
    special_tokens=[
        "<s>",
        "</s>",
        "<unk>",
        "<mask>",
        "<pad>",
    ]
)
```

but its giving me the error

> AttributeError: 'GPT2Tokenizer' object has no attribute 'train_from_iterator'

What is the correct method to use in this case? I am using `transformers` 4.4.2 and `tokenizers` 0.10.1. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if I really get it. GPT2 uses a `ByteLevelBPE` algorithm. What you need to do is to train such a [tokenizer](https://github.com/huggingface/tokenizers/blob/master/bindings/python/examples/train_bytelevel_bpe.py) and use it with your GPT2 model. You can even load generated the file with the GPT2Tokenizer in case you want to use some of the class attributes.

Comment: @cronoik You are right, I understood the usage of tokenizers incorrectly. Doing as you suggested got things working :)